# ArthurHub Image cropper not working properly in Fragment, asking for RESULT_OKAY to be defined manually

Tags: android

I am using image cropper tool by ArthurHub, found here https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

It is not working properly, after several tries on own I copied the code directly to try and debug where the problem lied. Below is my ```onActivityResult`` code for it

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageUri = result.getUri();
                profile.setImageURI(imageUri);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error: "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "RESULT Okay problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "RequestCode problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    }
```

The `RESULT_OKAY` was asked to be manually set and did not accept on its own, so I set to 5 randomly.

```
 private static final int RESULT_OK = 5;
```

Here is my call to the cropper tool

```
profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                             .start(getContext(), addMember.this);

            }
        });
```

After running the app I get the "RESULT Okay problem" toasted. So I am sure the problem lies in that value.

What should I be setting it to? Why was it not auto accepted like `CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE`

**Edit**

It works if I set resultCode to 5 as well, for example the below code runs

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        resultCode=5;
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageUri = result.getUri();
                profile.setImageURI(imageUri);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error: "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "RESULT Okay problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "RequestCode problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    }
```

Is this the correct way or it can lead to problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what the problem was. While inside a fragment if we need to use this, then we have to add (ParentActivityName).RESULT.OKAY

So the code would be actually

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

      
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                imageUri = result.getUri();
                profile.setImageURI(imageUri);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error: "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "RESULT Okay problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "RequestCode problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    }
```

Comment: Can use the new library https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper